# How to Implement Spring Integration int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-gateway with advanced Oracle type IN parameter

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, spring-integration

I am trying to implement a int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-gateway that executes a oracle store procedure with advanced oracle type IN parameter.

I am not clear about how to declare the advanced type for IN parameter.

The code and configuration are as bellow.

```
create or replace PROCEDURE POC2 
(
D_LIST IN MOVE_AUDIT,
DB_RESPONSE OUT VARCHAR2)
IS
BEGIN
.....
END POC2;

create or replace TYPE MOVE_AUDIT IS OBJECT
(
 MOVE_ID  VARCHAR2(50),
 MESSAGE  VARCHAR2(50)
);
create or replace TYPE MOVE_AUDIT_TAB IS TABLE OF MOVE_AUDIT;
```

stored-proc-outbound-gateway Configuration:

```
<int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-gateway
        id="inParamStorprocGateway" data-source="dataSource"
        request-channel="requestChannel" is-function="false"
        reply-channel="replyChannel" stored-procedure-name="POC2"
        expect-single-result="false" ignore-column-meta-data="true">
        <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition
            name="D_LIST" direction="IN" type="STRUCT" type-name="MOVE_AUDIT_TAB" return-type="sqlReturnStruct"/>
        <int-jdbc:sql-parameter-definition name="DB_RESPONSE" direction="OUT" type="VARCHAR"/>
        <int-jdbc:parameter name="D_LIST" expression="payload"/>
</int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-gateway>

<bean id="sqlReturnStructArrayConfirmPutway"    class="org.springframework.data.jdbc.support.oracle.SqlReturnStructArray">
    <constructor-arg name="mapper" ref="confirmPutawayStructMapper"/>
</bean>
<bean id="confirmPutawayStructMapper" class="com.test.mapper.ConfirmDomainStructMapper"/>
```

Bellow is the struct Mapper:

```
public class ConfirmDomainStructMapper implements StructMapper<ConfirmDomain> {

  public STRUCT toStruct(ConfirmDomain oDemoDomainObject, Connection conn, String typeName)
      throws SQLException {
    StructDescriptor descriptor = new StructDescriptor(typeName, conn);
    Object[] values = new Object[2];
    values[0] = oDemoDomainObject.getId();
    values[1] = oDemoDomainObject.getName();
    return new STRUCT(descriptor, conn, values);
  }

  public ConfirmDomain fromStruct(STRUCT struct) throws SQLException {
    ConfirmDomain oDemoDomainObject=null;
    if(null!=struct){
      oDemoDomainObject=new ConfirmDomain();
      Datum[] resArray=struct.getOracleAttributes();
      oDemoDomainObject.setId(resArray[0].stringValue());
      oDemoDomainObject.setName(resArray[1].stringValue());
    }
    return oDemoDomainObject;
  }

}
```

I tried and debugged this code but it does not call the toStruct method of the StructMapper.

From log I got the D_LIST passed is NULL

Comment: @Artem Bilan Can you Please help

Comment: Hi! I see the question. And I'll try to answer today. BTW I see you also don't how to correctly mention an SO user :-)

Comment: @ArtemBilan Now I got how to mention an SO user...  thanks :)

Comment: Yes, Agreed. Now I received a message from you. Thanks. And now I know how to do that too :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all I don't understand how your app runs at all, because of:

```
else {
    parameterBuilder = BeanDefinitionBuilder.genericBeanDefinition(SqlParameter.class);
    if (StringUtils.hasText(returnType)) {
        parserContext.getReaderContext().error("'return-type' attribute can't be provided " +
                            "for IN 'sql-parameter-definition' element.", storedProcComponent);
    }
}
```

So, `return-type` can be specified only for the `OUT` params.

Another issue with proc definition. I can guess it should have `D_LIST IN TYPE MOVE_AUDIT_TAB`, because, I think, you are going to store several object at once.

So, forget about `return-type` and that `ConfirmDomainStructMapper`, beucase it makes sence when you want to read `OUT` params.

This `<int-jdbc:parameter name="D_LIST" value="payload"/>` will only if your `payload` is really an object of that custom Oralce type.

From Java perspective that `IS TABLE OF` type called `ARRAY`. So you really should use some Oracle JDBC native code to create it.

I did that once and it looks like:

```
<transformer expression="@oracleArrayCreator.create(payload, '${scheme.name}.MOVE_AUDIT_TAB', '${scheme.name}.MOVE_AUDIT')"/>
```

Pay atention, please, that those type must be outside of any package. Otherwise Oracle JDBC Driver can't resolve them.

```
@Service
@org.springframework.context.annotation.Lazy
class OracleArrayCreator {

    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource

    @Autowired
    Properties internalProperties

    ARRAY create(List<Map> data, String tableName, String recordName) {
        def recordKeys = internalProperties.getProperty(recordName.replaceFirst(/.*\./, '')).split(',')
        def connection = nativeConnection
        def structDescriptor = StructDescriptor.createDescriptor(recordName, connection)

        def dataArray = []

        data.each { recordMap ->
            def record = []
            if (recordMap) {
                recordKeys.each {
                    record << recordMap[it]
                }
                dataArray << new STRUCT(structDescriptor, connection, record.toArray())
            }
        }

        new ARRAY(ArrayDescriptor.createDescriptor(tableName, connection), connection, dataArray.toArray())
    }


    ARRAY create(Map data, String tableName, String recordName) {
        create([data], tableName, recordName)
    }

    CLOB convertToClob(String value) {
        CLOB c = CLOB.createTemporary(nativeConnection, false, CLOB.DURATION_SESSION)
        c.setString(1L, value)
        return c
    }

    Connection getNativeConnection() {
        DataSourceUtils.getConnection(dataSource).metaData.connection
    }

}
```

(Sorry for Groovy code).

And place that `<transformer>` just before your `<int-jdbc:stored-proc-outbound-gateway>`. Of course, you can wrap them both to the `<chain>`.

And yes, `type="ARRAY"` should be for that `D_LIST` param.

Comment: Thanks @ArtemBilan . It is working perfectly.. Posting the latest configuration and Converter java code as well.

Comment: Great! Let's accept my answer to be sure that I did good work to help you ;-)

Comment: Hi @ArtemBilan Please check the bellow post. We are getting Deadlock very frequently.

Answer (score 0):

> Getting frequent thread blocking
>
> To get the connection,I am using

`Connection conn=DataSourceUtils.getConnection(datasource);`

> And to release : 
>   `DataSourceUtils.releaseConnection(conn);` in finally block

One Block thread.

```
http-/0.0.0.0:8081-73
oracle.sql.TypeDescriptor.getName(TypeDescriptor.java:682)
oracle.jdbc.oracore.OracleTypeCOLLECTION.isInHierarchyOf(OracleTypeCOLLECTION.java:149)
oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.processCompletedBindRow(OraclePreparedStatement.java:2063)
oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3579)
oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.execute(OraclePreparedStatement.java:3685)
oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.execute(OracleCallableStatement.java:4714)
oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.execute(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:1376)
sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor96.invoke(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
net.bull.javamelody.JdbcWrapper.doExecute(JdbcWrapper.java:403)
net.bull.javamelody.JdbcWrapper$StatementInvocationHandler.invoke(JdbcWrapper.java:128)
net.bull.javamelody.JdbcWrapper$DelegatingInvocationHandler.invoke(JdbcWrapper.java:285)
com.sun.proxy.$Proxy64.execute(Unknown Source)
```

> Another

```
http-/0.0.0.0:8081-71
oracle.sql.ARRAY.toBytes(ARRAY.java:675)
oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setArrayCritical(OraclePreparedStatement.java:5985)
oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setARRAYInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:5944)
oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setObjectCritical(OraclePreparedStatement.java:8782)
oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setObjectInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:8278)
oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.setObjectInternal(OraclePreparedStatement.java:8877)
oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.setObject(OracleCallableStatement.java:4992)
oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.setObject(OraclePreparedStatementWrapper.java:240)
sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor105.invoke(Unknown Source)
sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
```

Comment: @Artem Billan  Any suggestion.

Comment: You should talk to your DBA to investigate what's going on the Oracle side in that case. Sorry, I can't help with the Driver code. From other side it looks like a new SO question anyway.